# Lubuntu weather applet location settings

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, lxpanel, weather

How is one supposed to set their location for this thing? I've tried several ways to tell it where I am, and it's not accepting **anything** I type into it -- and I'm in a major US city, no less.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with lxde, that I could not enter a zipcode or large city into weather widget. I also installed my-weather-indicator too, and you can see both in screen shots. Here is how I got it to work:

1. Right click a blank area of your taskbar and choose "add/remove panel items".
2. Click "ADD" and select "application launch bar", and click "ADD". It will be added and look like a "+", move it where you want using "up/down".
   [ADD application launch bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPY80.png)
3. While it is still selected, choose preferences and select the + in front of "accessories" to expand the list. Select "weather" and "add".
   [Select weather and ADD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lco4H.png)
4. It is now in your panel and when you click on it, you will be able to edit the "place."

Answer (score 0):

It's a known ***Ubuntu*** bug in **lxpanel** *v0.8.1-1ubuntu2*, [#1539930 Cannot set Location in Weather Applet](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxpanel/+bug/1539930), first reported 1/30/16.

---

A substitute that works in LXDE is [my-weather-indicator](https://launchpad.net/my-weather-indicator).  Install it like so:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicator
```

On my laptop it didn't run until it was run from a terminal:

```
/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin/my-weather-indicator
```

When the *My-Weather* icon appears, left click it, then select `Preferences>General Options>Autostart`.  After rebooting, the *My-Weather* icon should be in whichever corner the other applets are.

Comment: This is not working well for me.  Once I enter /opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin/my-weather-indicator in the terminal the My-Weather Indicator window does come up and correctly accepts my changes, but even after completing the task and closing that My-Weather Indicator window the terminal continues to show status changes of the applet and if I close that terminal window the taskbar applet also disappears. How does one make the change permanent, or better yet, add it to the "Panel Applets" section of the "Panel Preferences" window?

  Thank you, David

Comment: @monkeyman_stones, when you see the *My-Weather* icon, left click it, then select `Preferences>General Options>Autostart`.  After rebooting, the icon should be there.

Comment: After a reboot it now appears, but as a desktop widget and taskbar applet.  If I close the desktop widget the taskbar applet closes also.  With sudo nano /home/david/.config/lxpanel/LXDE/panels/panel and changing to Plugin {
  type=weather
  Config {
    alias=Dover, MA
    city=Dover
    state=Massachusetts
    country=United States
    woeid=2393342
    units=f
    interval=10
    enabled=1
  }
}   Did not produce a change to the standard weather applet.  Sorry agc, I placed this reply as you entered your above post.

Comment: @monkeyman_stones, so is it working well now?

Comment: The application you suggested was functional but far too resource and user intensive for me to keep (I removed it). The standard weather taskbar application was not fixed by any of it (including my /home/david/.config/‌​lxpanel/LXDE/panels/p‌​anel changes) so things are roughly the same as prior to all edit attempts including my own.